# javascript and CSS versioning for Cache Busting in Tapestry

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, tapestry

I am new to Tapestry .
Is there a way with which we can do Cache Busting in tapestry .
I am interested in knowing that whether Tapestry is having some in-built capability to let us do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is built in. Assets (css, JavaScript, images) served up by Tapestry through the use of the asset: or context: binding prefix get unique URLs that change when the checksum of the asset (for Tapestry 5.4 and later) or app version number (for Tapestry 5.3 and earlier) changes. See the Asset Fingerprinting section of http://tapestry.apache.org/assets.html for details.

Comment: Thank you Bob for the answer. But is there any kind of reference where I can get more details ,like on how to implement this and what has to be considered for doing this ?

Comment: It's automatic, as long as you put the files in one of the correct places and reference the files using one of the documented approaches. All the details are there at http://tapestry.apache.org/assets.html

Comment: Thank you very much Bob...yes, I got it that it handles it automatically.